# Reapply svn merge without revert

Tags: svn, merge

We were performing svn merge from Trunk to a branch.
Unfortunately, we got into a bad state where there's a svn commit that fails because a local directory doesnt exist in the working copy. Yet the mergeinfo property is updated with the trunk revision numbers.

We do not know when the svn commit first fails and the svn merge has been going on for a while without our close attention.

We are thinking of reapplying svn merge of revision numbers in mergeinfo property without reverting (because there are so many revision numbers that have been merged).
Would that cause a problem to mergeinfo property ?

How do we guarantee that all the svn merges would go smoothly this time ?

Thank you
Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think you should conduct the merge again:

1. Revert the previous merge
2. Windows/Mac/Linux delete any unversioned and ignored files and folders
3. Do an `svn up --depth infinity` at the root of the branch checkout
4. Conduct the merge from trunk to the branch, paying attention to what happens

If you don't want to do this, then you *can* manually modify the mergeinfo to include the expected merged revisions from trunk, **but I would advise against it**.